# Autofac RegisterType for UsingConstructor that inherits from the constuctor parameter type

Tags: autofac, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way to tell Autofac to resolve a constructor parameter with a RegisteredType that inherits from the class used in the constructor?

I need to use the HttpClientHandler in the constructor for the HttpClient, but I need the HttpClientHandler to access GetCookies as well... If I register the handler As HttpMessageHandler, It creates the HttpClient properly, but then I have to cast HttpMessageHander to HttpClientHandler, which feels like a hack; Is there a better way to do it?

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpClientHandler>().As<HttpMessageHandler>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>().UsingConstructor(typeof(HttpMessageHandler)).SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't written a full test but I think you could insert an AsSelf() into your HttpClientHandler registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpClientHandler>()
       .As<HttpMessageHandler>()
       .AsSelf()
       .SingleInstance();
```

So when I am resolving, these come back without issue:
            var container = builder.Build();

```
        var handler = container.Resolve<HttpClientHandler>();
        var client = container.Resolve<HttpClient>();
```